# Glassfish error for new oracle jdbc pool: "Invalid Oracle URL specified: OracleDataSource.makeURL"

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, glassfish

I am trying to add a new connection pool to Glassfish 4.0.  Getting the following error:  "Invalid Oracle URL specified: OracleDataSource.makeURL".  All i have done is go into the admin console and enter the resource type as "javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource" and the datasource classname as "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource".  When i try to ping test from the console, the error occurs.

Comment: Is this because i am running Java 8?  Maybe the oracle driver only works under Java 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded Java from 1.8 to 1.7 and also setup the data pool via netbeans instead of the glass fish admin console and the problem is resolved.